React Router Navigation in Form submission
the navigation does not work , the react router is working correctly when i type down the URL manually also the Links
 const navigate = useNavigate();

 function handleForm() {
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    navigate("/");
  }

 <Form onSubmit={handleForm}>
...
</Form>


To navigate to another webpage in a function and not using Links

You can also use the arrow function to follow the newer ECMA script syntax ES6. Another reason is that you will not use lexical this probably so the arrow function is a better choice.
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const MyComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); 

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("Form Submitted"); 
    navigate("/");
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      {/* Form content */}
    </Form>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;


The above answer is correct. You should always include e.preventDefault() though in your case, it should have navigated without this too. Make sure the routes are defined and named correctly, double check it to be sure.
Also if the issue is not resolved, please share your App.jsx, where you are handling the navigation.
